# How to build network specific application in iOS (IP Mapping)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios6, ios7

I wanna build an ios application which must be network specific.i wanna put IP mapping in my app.
it should work in a particular network or simply it should not work in other network except one network which i specify. i have googled but didn't get clear answer.
please let me know any solution for this.

Comment: Are you accessing any web services from your app?

Comment: Yes i am using web service.

Comment: Please clear you idea about Network? What is could be for you with example

Comment: I guess what your looking for is IP whitelisting. This is done from the server side to limit access of services to only certain IPs(whitelisted ones).

Comment: @AashishJoshi i want to restrict my application for only one network.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple review [guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 2.22 Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected

It is risky to limit your app to one specific network and it will probably get rejected. All apps should provide minimum functionality to all users that download it. Also there is no ability to limit availability in the App Store to a specific network, you can only limit availability by country.

You can parse the external ip with an external service like [this](http://checkip.dyndns.com) (make a NSURLConnection and parse the result) and provide extra functionality to users from a specific network.